# Proof of `TWOSUM` implementation in "double-double" arithmetic

Tags: solution-verification, numerical-methods, floating-point

"double-double" / "compensated" arithmetic uses unevaluated sums of floating point numbers to obtain higher precision.

One of the basic algorithms is `TWOSUM`(a,b) = (x,y) where $x,y$ don't overlap each other (while $a,b$ might overlap), with all operations in machine-precision floating point:

```
x := a + b
z := x - a
y := (a - (x - z)) + (b - z)
```

I have seen it claimed that this is an "error-free transform".  I have not been able to prove it: my attempt by multiplying each operation by $(1 + \epsilon_k)$ in (wx)Maxima yields:

```
x : (a + b) * (1 + e[1])$
z : (x - a) * (1 + e[2])$
y : ((a - (x - z) * (1 + e[3])) * (1 + e[4]) + (b - z) * (1 + e[5])) * (1 + e[6])$
expand((x + y) - (a + b));
-> -e[3]*a + terms multiplied by more than one e[k]
```

That is, I think it's only error-free if `e[3]` is zero, that is, when `x - z` is exactly representable.  Is this always the case?  Why?

Comment: "error free" here means that $(x,y)$ contains all the information for the exact sum $a+b$, $y$ reconstructs the floating point error committed in the calculation of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reference that states a fact without proof:

> We shall not give the proof of this fact but point at the leading
> idea namely that $v_1$ and $u_1$ have been truncated precisely to have only
> zeros to the right of what are the significant positions of $s$.
>
> -- Møller, O. Quasi double-precision in floating point addition. BIT 5, 37–50 (1965). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01975722

$s$ corresponds to $x$, $v_1$ corresponds to $z$ and $u_1$ corresponds to $x - z$ in the notation in my question.  That $z$ is truncated to $x$ thus means that $x - z$ is exactly representable, and so `e[3]` is indeed zero, and the difference between $x + y$ and $a + b$ is at most epsilon squared smaller than the value.